# How do I right-align the second span to the lower right of the div?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the **Midweek Meeting Schedule** to align to the right edge? But not lose layout? I tried a `div` with `float: right` but it was not right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>CONGREGATION NAME</title>
<style type="text/css">

body{
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: #666;
}

.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}

.containerMeeting {

}

.textCongregation {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.textTitle {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

@media print {
    body{
        background: #FFF;
    }

    .containerPage, .containerMeeting,  {
        width: 99%;
        min-width: 99%;
        max-width: 99%;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

}</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px grey solid;">
            <div style="border-bottom: 4px red solid; margin-bottom: 2px;">
                <span class="textCongregation">Congregation Name</span>
                <span class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Also tried:

```
<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px grey solid;">
            <div style="border-bottom: 4px red solid; margin-bottom: 2px;">
                <span class="textCongregation" style="float:left">Congregation Name</span>
                <span class="textTitle" style="float:right">Midweek Meeting Schedule</span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the text is aligning downwards.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? Hard to visualise without

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay3hectf/

Answer (score 1):

an alternative solution: use a table: Create an additional `div` around the two elements in question (or use the existing div that has `border-bottom: 4px red solid; margin-bottom: 2px;` for this), make that surrounding container `display: table; width: 100%;` and assign the two to-be-aligned elements `display: table-cell` and a fixed or percentage width.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Or just do an actual table with one row and two cells. The important thing too is that the two outermost divs are untouched so the two horizontal borders stay at same width.

Comment: here are my findings. I did indeed get it to work using these display settings. But only in Internet Explorer. When the same file was viewed within my program that uses CHtmlView, it didn't display them side by side. I decided to use a table in the end with two cells. With the table being inside the two outer divs.

Answer (score 0):

a `<span>` element is by default an `inline` element and therefore cannot be aligned or floated. However, you can change its `display` property to `display: block`. Then you can use `float` (left or right) on it, or define it as absolutely positioned and align it right with `right: 0px`(However, with the latter you will also have to adjust the vertical position (for example with `top: 100px`) if you do that on more than one element.

Comment: Would it be better then if I use two div objects instead of span objects?

Comment: probably yes. If you float them or use absoulte position (and a fixed or percentage-based width) on them, you can align them left and right.

Comment: I changed to divs. But the text on right was overlapping. I made outer divs both 18 point font. Now right one not overlap. But left one with shorter font height is aligning to top of div. 

Answer (score 0):

You can set `text-align` only to block elements (e.g. div), not to inline elements (e.g. span, b, a).

As @Johannes said, make the two spans to divs. But I won't suggest using float and the `top` property – this maybe won't work on smaller screens when the text wraps. Instead, use a flex layout.

Set the direct container as flex container by adding `display: flex`. Also add `justify-content: space-between` to make the both text divs be at the ends. At last, add `align-items: baseline` to make the texts be on the same horizontal baseline. That's it!

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay3hectf/5/

Edit: Here's a good guide on how to use flex layouts: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: By the way: Pleeease remove this `min-width: 210mm;` property; it'll make the header much more mobile friendly! Just resize your browser window and you'll see what I mean ;-)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, it should work with HTML4; a problem could be whether the browser supports flex boxes. Have a look at this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox